# Bootstrap dropdown customization on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown which I have made using `bootstrap-select`. Below is the code for the same:

HTML

```
 <select class="selectpicker">
     <option>Mustard</option>
     <option>Ketchup</option>
     <option>Relish</option>
 </select>
```

JS:

```
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        style: 'btn-select',
        size: 2
 });
```

On hover I want the background-color of the caret to go yellow, something like this [image]

I have changed the CSS of the caret like below:

```
.btn-select
{
    background-color: #FFF !important;
    border: 1px solid #9EBBDE !important;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
}


.btn-select span.bs-caret
{
    height:10px !important;
    width:10px !important;    
}


.btn-select:hover span.bs-caret
{
    background-color: #FDE481;   
}
```

But this is not working. Is there any workaround for the same?

Here is a non-working [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Ouy01bNbCQ#) of the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap `caret` is built using border. Setting the background-color would not help the cause. You can use the pseudo element `:before` or `:after` to get the effect you wanted. Working code http://www.bootply.com/O0W1KwLQSr

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)